# How to use it correctly Vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

So I'm currently facing logical problem problem on how to store data in Vuex.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="category in sub_categories" @click="setProductCategory(category);">
        <span v-bind:class="{active: category == product.category}"></span>
        <a>{{ category.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="resultObject" v-if="product.category">
    <span class="active">{{ product.category.name }}</span>
</p>
```

The `category` object contains a lot of data about category such as icon, title, path and etc. and the `product` object will be sent to the server so basically it need only `category.id` property.

So my question is should I store whole category object in product in Vuex or just `@click="setProductCategory(category.id);"` and then do some extra stuff to show category name ?

Comment: Personally i would store the whole object in the store. Its particularly useful if the data is reused. Just grab the ID in your service for sending to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation, if category object is large & then repetition of the same category records along with products. So it's better to keep flat structure small objects in store.

Comment: nope, it's more about sending it to the server. Before sending I need to exclude most data because on the server I only need `category_id`